# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this error how can I fix this one? I'm trying to get the detail from local storage through **SessionParser.js** https://github.com/jethroacosta08/sessionparser. I'm trying toLocaleString the Tuition on the data.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined
    at paymentStd (onClick.js:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (database.html:1)
```

onclick.js

```
    function paymentStd(i){
        var data = lp.getKey('StudentsData','Students_Information')[i];
        var data_all = lp.getKey('StudentsData','Students_Information');
        $('#full_name').text(data.FirstName+" "+data.MiddleName+" "+data.LastName);
        $('#StudentID').text(data.StudentID);



        var Tuition = data.Tuition.toLocaleString();
        console.log(Tuition);
        $('#paymentStudent').text('Php '+ Tuition+'.00');
        $('#prints').click(function(){
            window.print();
        });





    }
```

Comment: Debug data using console.log(data), that variable was probably incorrectly getted or just data.Tuition is incorrectly accessed or setted. But the console.log will tell exactly the right name of Tuition or if it even exists on Data, also if it is not a string .toLocaleString() cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that data.Tuition is defined(Has a value). Only then you can use the toLocaleString method

Answer (score 0):

The best answer would be to check if data. Tuition is defined, and to check that you can add an if condition before using the TOLOCALESTRING function so that we can confirm that the function only runs if the variable has an actual value.

Second also add the optional chaining operator.
The **optional chaining operator (?.)** enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.
[Optional Chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

In this way:

```
let Tuition;
if (data.Tuition ! = null)
    Tuition = data.Tuition.toLocaleString?.();
```

I hope this will surely work, if not comment on my answer and I will then look into it further.